# GPS Magnetic Declination and current database

Tags: gnss

Can I fly with an expired GPS database if I verify the waypoints locations? or is the magnetic declination part of the database?

Comment: I believe this question has been answered here:  https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/11568/can-i-use-an-expired-ifr-certified-gps-with-an-out-of-date-database-in-lieu-of-d

Comment: Per your comments about magnetic declination, I don't think that is updated on a yearly basis in the GPS.  The VFR charts show the 2015 value for Isogonic lines.  The actual magnetic declination today is a little different than what the charts depict.